# Pushing data into an array model in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, i have a conceptual problem and a real error... i'm working on an inventory module concept, is simple, it consist on two models:

- Inventory
- Item

The Inventory model just contains a "items" field, and that field is just a reference (to populete) to the real item object models, you know `items: [type: String, ref: 'Item']`.

The Item object is the real data container, it have all data (name, itemCode, description, disponibility, existence... and so on). The problem in the concept is confusing for me.

When an item is created, it need to be pushed into the array "items" of Inventory model document, i coded this snippet, but it retrieve me an error:

```
var inventario = new Inventario(); //The inventory document instance

var inventarios = router.route('/inventarios');

inventarios.post(function(req, res) {
// itamdata object
var nuevoItem = {
    _id: req.body._id,
    descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
    costo: req.body.costo,
    precioMin: req.body.precioMin,
    precioMax: req.body.precioMax,
    existencia: req.body.existencia,
    disponible:req.body.disponible
  };
  // Create a new item
  Item.Create(nuevoItem, function(err, item) {
    if(err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        msg: 'Problema interno con la base de datos',
        error: err
      });
    }
    // call push from push method of documents array
    inventario.items.push({ _id: nuevoItem._id });

    res.status(200).json({msg: 'Item Creado', token: item});
  }); // fin Item.Create

}); //fin inventarios.post
```

The error is: `/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:482
  this.stack.push(layer);
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`

My concept is really simple, and i tested the requires and exports of models, all looks fine, so, anyone have some idea to solution the problem?

Comment: Looks like problem with your Inventario() constructor. Can you please show that code.

Comment: @KiranPagar i rewrite all the code in one more friendly structure and the error was solved... now i'm getting another strange error, some like `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: That's pretty common error, here is excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

Error comes when you are sending the name of the field in schema and in api file wrong or in your HTML page and `req.body` parameter names incorrect.
Another way can be try using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
```

in your server.js file.